# how to make Fancybox popup full width with scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am trying to make my fancybox images that pop up full screen rather than pop up to fit in viewport.

Here is an example of a popup on my site currently:

[image]

As you can see it is fitting in viewport but is very narrow. How can I make this wider and allow it to scroll?

Here is my code:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding: 0,
        autoScale: false
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to set full width with scroll.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : '100%',
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '100%',
    height      : 'auto',
    autoSize    : false,
    helpers : {
          overlay : {
              locked: false
          }
    }
});
```